# RDF4J rdf lucene configuration

Tags: lucene, rdf, sesame, openrdf, rdf4j

I have been trying for some time to configure my sesame RDF repository (at the moment is called RDF4j) in order to use full text queries.

I did not find much documentation about this configuration, I think that I need to create a template file so then I can use it with the console. Here is the little information about the topic https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rdf4j-users/xw2UJCziKl8

Does anybody know any information about the configuration of RDF4j with Lucene? Any clue would be very appreciate. Otherway, I would think about change the whole repository for another, like for example virtuoso.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is, but documentation for the Lucene Sail is available in the RDF4J documentation: http://rdf4j.org/doc/programming-with-rdf4j/customization-sails/#Full_text_indexing_with_the_Lucene_SAIL

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these operations:

1. Start rdf4j-server. I used rdf4j-server.war (and rdf4j-workbench.war). My url was http://127.0.0.1:8080/rdf4j-server
2. Put lucene.ttl ([lucene.ttl](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvtPqXCz3knjiW8WZXBzLM2PZhm_) or [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9vmnMuEyN3VNDBHN0ptdUpjQTA/view)) into ~/.RDF4J/console/templates, where "~" your home directory
3. Correct settings in this file
4. Then start console from rdf4j distributive

Then execute next commands in console:

```
connect http://127.0.0.1:8080/rdf4j-server
create lucene
Enter lucene repository Id: myRepositoryId
Enter lucene repository name: myRepositoryName
```

Then you can see in http://127.0.0.1:8080/rdf4j-workbench created repository. If you add some triples you can use [lucene search](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_full_text_indexing_with_the_lucene_sail)